# Extracting strings from an API .json in html

Tags: php, html, json

I'm new to html (practically sero experience) and I wanted to extract a string from an api .json response.
I tried with php in html but I think that I'm bad with it because I can't get anything from it.

What their API example looks like :

```
<?php
//Get the status and decode the JSON
$status = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://api.mcsrvstat.us/2/domain.tld'));

//Show the version
echo $status->version;

//Show a list of players
foreach ($status->players->list as $player) {
    echo $player.'<br />';
}
?>
```

How I tried to implement it in html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<?php
//Get the status and decode the JSON
$status = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://api.mcsrvstat.us/2/labrofamily.aternos.me'));

//Show the version
echo $status->version;

//Show a list of players
foreach ($status->players->list as $player) {
    echo $player.'<br />';
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

And the output of this :

> version; //Show a list of players foreach ($status->players->list as $player) { echo $player.'
> '; } ?>

Comment: You can’t use php in a html file. Save the file as .php and run on a server.

Comment: @Villanelle "*You can’t use php in a html file*" ***CITATION NEEDED*** - also provably false. It's possible (and a relatively common configuration) for Apache to be configured to run files with `.html` extensions through PHP.

Comment: This is a web server configuration problem.  Make sure you're running PHP on your server.  Also, if you'd like, you can access this API client-side with JavaScript instead, and then you don't have to worry about what you have server-side.

Answer (score -2):

Your code looks fine, just save it as PHP file (not html), then run it on your webserver or PC using for example xampp.

Comment: The answer provided does not seem to address the issue raised.